# Why does this method updates react state very slowly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-state

I have two components. Parent component: Board and child component Cell. I am rendering 9 Cells using a loop in the Board component.

This is the child component(Cell.js):

```
function Cell(props) {
    return <button style={style} className='cells' id={props.id} onClick={(e) => { props.handleclick(e) }}>{props.text}</button>;
}
```

This is the Parent component(Board.js):

```
function Board() {
    let [board, setBoard] = useState(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']);
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        let newBoard = [...board];
        newBoard[2] = "0";
        setBoard(newBoard);
    }
    return <div style={style}>
        {board.map((item, i) => {
            return <><Cell handleclick={handleClick} text={item} key={i} /></>
        })
        }
    </div>
}
```

This works perfectly but there is another method I tried where I made some changes in the handleClick method.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
        let newBoard = board;
        newBoard[2] = "0";
        setBoard(newBoard);
    }
```

This takes too much time to change the state. State is getting changed that I have confirmed by looking at the react components in React Dev tools. What I am not able to understand it why this method takes too much time to update the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newBoard = board;
newBoard[2] = "0";
setBoard(newBoard);
```

You are mutating the state. When you set state in a function component, react does a `===` between the old and new state. Since it's the same array, react thinks nothing has changed, and so the component does not rerender. It might *never* render, though in your case it looks like some other component eventually sets state and causes a rerender.

Instead, always create a new state:

```
let newBoard = [...board];
newBoard[2] = "0";
setBoard(newBoard);
```

Comment: I am 100% sure that there is not other state getting changed other than this as there is only board as state in entire app. So still stuck at the same question. Why the delay in rerender

Comment: The reason it's not rerendering right away is that you are mutating state. Fix that to render right away. Everything else is just me making educated guesses. I would need to see your entire codebase (and probably do some debugging) to know for sure what is causing the eventual render.

Comment: Is there any way I can show you entire code except for copy pasting here. It's a small code not much is there. But i would really like to understand why the delay is going on

Comment: You could use an online code editor, such as [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lake-v6dym2)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-morse-n745uy   Done. I have uploaded both the method. the one that works slowly is uncommented and it does update the state just give it a few seconds.

Comment: `it does update the state just give it a few seconds.` I click and then wait, but i never see it rerender, no matter how long i wait. Are you doing anything else besides clicking? For example, are you re-saving the file which triggers hot module reloading?

Comment: Yes it seems that now it is not updating the state. and no I did not do anything else than clicking

Comment: "You are mutating the state" Does it mean that when I am doing newBoard = board JS is using a reference instead of making a different copy?

Comment: Correct. It's just giving you an additional reference to the existing array.